# why different protocol data units for different layers?

Tags: networking

we all know that for different layers in OSI model there are different PDU's ..

Like for transport layer we have segments

For data link layer we have frames.

so my question is why such different units were given for respective layers.. 
why all the layers cannot follow one single format ..?

Answer (score 0):

All the layers have different functionality. they add header (and tailer too if Data link layer) to the pdu passed by the layer above.
Since their functions are differernt the info present in headers and tailers attached at various layers also differ. and since they are different why to consider them as same.. thus layers cannot have single format.
For details :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 0):

Functionalities  differ in each layer. For ex Physical layer send as bits  , transport layer ensures packets (packetizing) are delivered between nodes.....and so on